# How to prove this conjectured identity related to hypergeometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function, polya-urn-model

**Question**: How to prove the following conjecture? ...

**Conjecture**: For all integers $r\ge 0$ and $b\ge 3$,

$$ {\LARGE\sum}_{j=2}^\infty{\LARGE\sum}_{i=j-2}^\infty{(r)_i(b)_j\over (r+b)_{i+j}}\binom{i}{j-2}(i+j)\ =\ \left(1+{r\over b-1}\right)\left(2+{r\over b-2}\right)$$

where the Pochhammer symbols are defined as $$(a)_n = \begin{cases}   1   &\text{ if }n = 0 \\
  a(a+1)(a+2)\cdots (a+n-1) &\text{ if } n > 0.
 \end{cases}$$

**Note**: This is motivated by [a previous as-yet-unanswered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2560846/16397). The LHS is the expected value of the first-occurrence time of $\tt BB$ in the sequence of colors drawn in a [Polya Urn Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_urn_model) that initially has $b$ $\tt{B}$lue balls and $r$ $\tt{R}$ed balls. The RHS is the result of inspecting pseudorandom simulations of the process for a variety of $(b,r)$ values.